# How to get maximum number of products matched vendors list. But i don't want to check same products again

Tags: mysql

How to get maximum products match vendors list 
[Please check this DB structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cS18f.jpg).

Comment: products match? please elaborate..

Comment: Welcome to SO. explain ur question clearly.. Look at minus votes.

Comment: I need to get maximum number of products matched vendors list. But i don't want to check same products again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Count with Order by

```
Select Count(pro_id) as total From table 
Group by vendor_id Order by Count(pro_id)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's works with me.  But i don't want to check same products again.

Comment: if my answer helps you please accept my answer  :)- @MuruganInnoblitz